# Corbel font missing in libreoffice under Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fonts, libreoffice

I have to use Corbel font in some documents in libreoffice under Ubuntu. By default, it seems that they are not available. I haven't found any package containing them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Corbel is a Microsoft font, so you'll have to do a bit of work:

1. Download the PowerPoint Viewer .exe: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6
2. Open a terminal and change your working directory to where you downloaded the above file (`cd`)
3. Run `sudo apt-get install cabextract`
4. Run `cabextract -F ppviewer.cab PowerPointViewer.exe`
5. Run `sudo mkdir /usr/share/fonts/vista`
6. Run `sudo cabextract -F '*.TT?' -d /usr/share/fonts/vista ppviewer.cab`
7. Run `fc-cache -fv`

Source: http://www.oooninja.com/2008/01/calibri-linux-vista-fonts-download.html